# How to change rownum only if the next row is distinct

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this

| RowNum | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | Z |
| 5 | Z |
| 6 | Z |
| 7 | V |

and I want something like this

| RowNum | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Z |
| 3 | Z |
| 3 | Z |
| 4 | V |

How can I do that in Oracle?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way - using the `match_recognize` clause, available since Oracle 12.1. Note that `rownum` is a reserved keyword, so it can't be a column name; I changed it to `rnum` in the input and `rn` in the output, adapt as needed.

The `with` clause is not part of the query - it's there just to include your sample data. Remove it before using the query on your actual data.

```
with
  inputs (rnum, value) as (
    select 1, 'X' from dual union all
    select 2, 'X' from dual union all
    select 3, 'Y' from dual union all
    select 4, 'Z' from dual union all
    select 5, 'Z' from dual union all
    select 6, 'Z' from dual union all
    select 7, 'V' from dual
  )
select rn, value
from   inputs
match_recognize (
  order by rnum
  measures match_number() as rn
  all rows per match
  pattern  ( a+ )
  define   a as value = first(value)
);

RN VALUE
-- -----
 1 X    
 1 X    
 2 Y    
 3 Z    
 3 Z    
 3 Z    
 4 V
```

In Oracle 11.2 and earlier, you can use the start-of-group method (the flags created in the subquery and counted in the outer query):

```
select count(flag) over (order by rnum) as rn, value
from   (
         select rnum, value, 
                case lag(value) over (order by rnum) 
                     when value then null else 1 end as flag
         from   inputs
       )
;
```

Comment: We only have Oracle 11g :/

Comment: @Praxusa - I just noticed that in your tags, and I added a solution that should work in older versions.